# How to get href value from a button (without link) using HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I'm trying access a webPage that uses so much JavaScript.

I need to do a pdf download, but using request and not click methods from htmlUnit. But I dont know what is the url.

I have the button:

```
<button id="j_idt29" name="j_idt29" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only RedButton" onclick="PrimeFaces.onPost();" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">PDF Donwload </span></button>
```

Obs.: I can't provide the web page url, it's stealthy.

In Js file:

```
onPost: function () {
        this.nonAjaxPosted = true;
        this.abortXHRs()
},
```

Comment: can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Seems this website is posting a form `onclick="PrimeFaces.onPost();" type="submit"`. You need to provide more info for tihs function

Comment: @yueyou I edited my question, I find the function

Comment: I think this function is just used to aborting XHR. How about the form submission method

Answer (score 0):

Search in the js for

```
PrimeFaces.onPost();
```

the link will be set there

Comment: Using Chrome Dev Tools: I open the tab Sources, ctrl + shift + f and I can't find for PrimeFaces.onPost, I get : "No matches found". I edit my question with a image

Comment: just search onPost(); then and also search in de html file itself

Comment: I edited my question again, with the function. In htmlFile I find just references to the function, like the button element.

Comment: Now search for abortXHRs()
Also look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: The function is just:  b.ajax.Queue.abortAll(). I read about this function and in wikipedia, and is just used to stop pending requests . I don't understand why the url doesn't appear in this function or in rest of the Js File.

Comment: Is the button in a form?

Comment: Yes, is in a form: <form id="j_idt12" name="j_idt12" method="post" action="/ceat/emitCert.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

Comment: /ceat/emitCert.xhtml is where it al happens

Comment: I installed the app Postman, and I think I found the download request. You're sure about the url. Do you wanna edit your answer? Thanks